# Secure Socket Layer SDK

Tags: cordova, ssl, sdk, ssl-certificate

Is there any SDK s available for developing **SECURE SOCKET LAYER** mobile applications developed with HTML/CSS/Javascript ??

Comment: HTML and CSS are both irrelevant to the question, and JavaScript already has HTTPS available.

Comment: @EJP : No i want an SDk that supports SSL for mobile app development

Comment: is der any such thing ??

Comment: I'm not aware that anything other than HTTP and HTTPS is available from JavaScript, but I could be wrong.

Comment: So if i have a service on my server how do i make the communication with that service SECURE ?

Comment: Now it is over http. to make it secure i must use https na ??

Comment: Yes, I just said that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SSL is enabled on the server not on the client. What SSL do is to encrypt traffic between a client and server. All clients with modern browsers or webkits are by default SSL compatible.  To enable SSL, you need to buy an SSL certificate from a certificate issuing authority like Godaddy, Verisign etc. and install on your server. a certificate is a private public key pair which does public key encryption. Here is a good video explaining SSL. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iQsKdtjwtYI . So bottom line is that you don't have to worry about SSL on the client side. once you get your service or php link up and running using SSL, just access the url using https on your client side. It is no different than accessing it over **http**.

Comment: OK...This answer explains me well...It is some certificate to be brought and installed on the server machine.. NO NEED TO DO ANY PROGRAMMING LINE OF CODE FOR THAT ????

Comment: Exactly! You need to worry only about data access using javascript and presentation using HTML5 and CSS3!

Answer (score 0):

SSL will be handled by your WebKit and OS. Its transport layer security and your developing applications using HTML/CSS and Javascript in application layer. so if you have a service which is secured using SSL, say https://mydomain.com/myservice, you can very well access this service using https and the transport layer will automatically be secure.

Comment: yes i do have a service running on a server...bu it is not https !!! it is like http://www.mydomain.com//myservice
so how do i make ot run on a secure layer "https" ??

Comment: if we dont have any service on the server and if we use php as server side scripting, then how do we enable SSL ?